# Not understanding valid argument form with implies, modus ponens

Tags: logic

I understand that if you have

if *p* then *q*
*p*
$\therefore$ *q*

that when "if *p* then *q*" is true, and you know *p* to be true, then it follows that *q* is true.

What I don't get is: wouldn't you have to know the truth of *p* and *q* beforehand? How else would you know if the implication "if *p* then *q*" is true or not?

For example:

If the sum of the digits of 371,487 is divisible by 3, then 371,487 is divisible by 3
The sum of the digits of 371,487 is divisible by 3
$\therefore$ 371,487 is divisible by 3

I could also have

If the sum of the digits of 371,487 is divisible by 3, then 17 is divisible by 3
The sum of the digits of 371,487 is divisible by 3
$\therefore$ 17 is divisible by 3

Clearly, in the second one, the conclusion is certainly not true, but the premise is, making the implication not true. In other words, you would have to know that either statement in the implication is true. But that would make the rest of the statements in the sequence a moot point.

Clearly, I don't understand how this works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid argument form is valid, irregardless of the truth values of the relevant variables.

What we have, with modus ponens, is the argument form:

$$\begin{align} & \;p\rightarrow q \\ &\;p \\ & \hline \\ \therefore & \;q\end{align}$$

This is valid, whatever the truth values of $p$ and $q$.

What this means is that we essentially have an argument that goes as follows:

> **IF** $\;(p \rightarrow q)\;$ is true, and **IF** $\;(p)\;$ is true, then necessarily, $q$ is true.

A valid argument form doesn't mean that the guarantee that $p\rightarrow q$ is necessarily true, nor that $p$ is necessarily true, but rather, it guarantees that *whenever* it *is the case* that both premises *are* true, then the conclusion is necessarily true, as well.

Comment: An argument form is also valid regardless of the truth values of the relevant variables. ;) Just for completeness, also note that an argument form is said to be _sound_ when its premises are _actually_ true (and the argument is valid).  You can't be sure of the conclusion of a valid argument unless you also know that it's a sound argument.

Comment: I completely get it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> What I don't get is: wouldn't you have to know the truth of p and q beforehand? How else would you know if the implication "if p then q" is true or not?

No.  Here are some examples of statements where "if p then q" is obviously true, but we know nothing about p or q:

1. If Bill is taller than me, then Bill is taller than everyone shorter than me.
2. If I live next door to Emily, and Joe lives next door to me, then Joe does not live next door to Emily.
3. If $f$ is a continuous function, then $f$ has a well-defined Riemann integral on every compact interval.

Since you don't know who Bill is, you obviously don't know if he's taller than me, or if he's taller than anyone else for that matter.  That is, we don't know whether p or q are true, but do we know that p implies q.

Comment: Right, so it doesn't always apply. But what about the examples that I put up? You still have these implications as well. For example the second example of the sequence of statements with division by 3, how would that work? Then you would have to know if both *p* and *q* are true, right? I'm just trying to figure out "if *p* then *q*, *p*, therefore *q*" actually works.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Consider the following statement, though: "If $n$ is divisible by 3, then $10n$ is divisible by 3."  That statement is true without knowing anything about $n$.

Comment: I guess the core of my question comes down to trying to understand valid arguments, valid argument forms, etc. In the book I'm reading  it starts out with "if *p* then *q*, *p*, therefore *q*" and I can't wrap my head around it. They use the example that I've given (with the division by 3), but it just doesn't seem (excuse the pun) logical to me. They say that the truth of the conclusion follows *necessarily* from the truth of its premises.

Comment: I re-read your question.  In the book's example, both premises are true, so the conclusion is true.  In your variant, one premise is true and the other is false, so we know nothing about whether the "conclusion" is true.

Comment: Right, so what I thought was that if "if *p* then *q*, *p*, therefore *q*" is a valid argument form, that it would mean that it doesn't matter what you fill in for *p* and *q* in "if *p* then *q*", *q* would always be true. But I guess that it isn't that simple, you really need to look at what the actual statements are.

Comment: If both "if p then q" and "p" are true, then "q" is also true.  In your example, "if p then q" is not true.